# When unit testing my ViewModel, list always returns empty

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

I'm trying to learn unit testing, I have my code factored into an MVVM(i) architecture, but when I run my testParseToList() test function, it always comes back with an empty list and I can't figure out why.  I fear it may have something to do with the i part of the MVVM(i) and whether or not I'm correctly mocking my viewmodel.  I'm starting with my most simple viewmodel in hopes to get a grasp of the concepts before moving onto my more complex ones.

**OfflineViewModelUnitTest.kt**

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class OfflineViewModelUnitTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    var offlineViewModel: OfflineViewModel = OfflineViewModel(OfflineInteractorImpl())

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        DaggerOfflineViewModelComponent.builder()
            .offlineInteractorImplModule(OfflineInteractorImplModule())
            .build()
            .inject(offlineViewModel)

//        this.offlineViewModel = OfflineViewModel(OfflineInteractorImpl())
    }

    @Test
    fun testParseToList() {

        val test = offlineViewModel.parseTextToList("dried bonito extract,\n" +
                "    ketchup,\n" +
                "    millet,\n" +
                "    corn & wheat protein")

        val a = "dried bonito extract"
        val b = "ketchup"
        val c = "millet"
        val d = "corn & wheat protein"

        val expectedResult = listOf(a, b, c, d)

        assertEquals(expectedResult, test)
    }
}
```

**OfflineViewModel.kt**

```
class OfflineViewModel(private val offlineInteractor: OfflineInteractor): ViewModel() {

    init {
        DaggerOfflineViewModelComponent.builder()
            .offlineInteractorImplModule(OfflineInteractorImplModule())
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }
    fun parseTextToList(firebaseVisionTextString: String): MutableList<String> {
        Log.d("here it is", firebaseVisionTextString)
        return offlineInteractor.parseTextToList(firebaseVisionTextString)
    }

    fun readCsvFromAssetFolder(inputStream: InputStream): List<String>{
        return offlineInteractor.readCsvFromAssetFolder(inputStream)
    }
}
```

**OfflineInteractorImpl.kt**

```
class OfflineInteractorImpl: OfflineInteractor {

    override fun parseTextToList(firebaseVisionTextString: String): MutableList<String> {

            val ingredientsList: MutableList<String> = firebaseVisionTextString.split(",").map { it.trim() }.toMutableList()

            return ingredientsList
    }

    override fun readCsvFromAssetFolder(inputStream: InputStream): List<String> {
        val csvLine: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        var content: Array<String>?
        try
        {
            val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            for (line in br.lines())
            {
                content = line.split((",").toRegex()).dropLastWhile{ it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                csvLine.add(content[0].substringBefore(";"))
            }
            br.close()
        }
        catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return csvLine
    }
}
```

**Test Results**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :[dried bonito extract, ketchup, millet, corn & wheat protein]
Actual   :[]
```

Comment: `offlineViewModel` is your class under test, yet you mocked it. You should not mock the class under test. Also if you create a mock you need to define the behaviour for it or else it will only return `null` (or the primitive equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Like second said, since you mocked offlineViewModel it is going to return an empty string, unless you define something for it to return using when().

Source: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-values-do-mocks-return-by-default